# Broadcast receiver multiple call when sender loop is fast?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my app, i have an activity with a broadcast receiver which receives messages from a service. The service contains a loop. In the loop it may decide to download data or read data from storage if exists. When data is downloaded from internet (each loop cycle takes about 1 sec), broadcast receiver works well. But when data is read from storage (5 loop cycles occur in maybe a milisecond), then broadcast receiver is called 5 times when last loop cycle is finished! Any solution or workaround?

Here is a schematic of my service:

```
 MyService extends Service{

 void foo(){
     for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
         if (file.exists()){
            myArrayList = readFile(fileName);
            System.out.println("cycle done " + (i+1));
            myIntent.putExtra("loop number" , (i+1));
            sendBroadcast(myIntent);                
         } else {
            myArrayList = downloadData(myUrl);
            System.out.println("cycle done " + (i+1));
            myIntent.putExtra("loop number" , (i+1));
            sendBroadcast(myIntent);
         }
 }
 }
```

And a schematic of broadcast receiver:

```
MyActivity extends Activity {
//some code here
private BroadcastReceiver myBr = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           System.out.println("myBr called " + intent.getExtra("loop number"));                                        
      }
};
```

Here is a sample log for when all loop cycles are getting data from internet:

```
cycle done 1
myBr is called 1
cycle done 2
myBr is called 2
cycle done 3
myBr is called 3
cycle done 4
myBr is called 4
cycle done 5
myBr is called 5
...
```

And finally a sample log for when all loop cycles are getting data from storage:

```
cycle done 1
cycle done 2
cycle done 3
cycle done 4
cycle done 5
myBr is called 5
myBr is called 5
myBr is called 5
myBr is called 5
myBr is called 5
```

Comment: use local bound service pattern then

Comment: Can't change the pattern. This pattern is used throughout my app. Changing it consumes time and i'm actually out of time.

Comment: so send your broadcast from a Runnable posted via Handler#post

Comment: tested but didn't help!

Comment: ok so `sendBroadcast` is asynchronous and your only option is a bound service (most likely local bound service)